Is the statement "I am the Immaculate Conception" pertaining to a Divine Person?
In the Lourdes apparition in 1858, the young Bernadette asked a question to a Lady in her vision, saying....
"Who are you?"
The Lady answered, "I am the Immaculate Conception".
Was the answer pertaining to a Divine Person speaking before Bernadette?
Was the Lady introduced Herself as a Divine Being?
https://ollsm.com/story-of-lourdes#:~:text=Our%20Lady%20of%20Lourdes%20is,properties%2C%20active%20to%20this%20day.
Note: The Dogma of the Immaculate Conception is not about a Divine Person, but how the Blessed Virgin Mary was conceived, as the dogma clearly stated,
"...at the first instance of conception, Mary was free from all stain of original sin..."

What Is the Immaculate Conception?


The Immaculate Conception is a Catholic dogma that states that Mary, whose conception was brought about the normal way, was conceived without original sin or its stain. That’s what “immaculate” means: without stain.

https://www.catholic.com/tract/immaculate-conception-and-assumption
Clearly, the dogma is not referring to a Divine Person, but describing how Mary was conceived free from original sin and its stain.
Now back to specific question.
The young Bernadette asked, "Who are you?"
Clearly, this is asking who is the person that she was seeing, and not how this person is conceived.
So, when the Lady in the vision answered,
"I am the Immaculate Conception"
Was the Lady introducing a Divine Being, a different being from Herself?

I dare the three person who downvoted the question, to justify their vote. If I found their downvote justifiable, I will delete this post at once. If none justify their downvote, then the CSE Admin must suspend this three members who are clearly downvoting my numerous post without even stating the grounds. These people are plain coward or must be crazy, pardon for the word, but they are indeed crazy in my view.

@Ken Graham point to me, the error on this question? The downvoters cannot justify their grounds. They lacks serious theological defense, am I correct?

"Was the Lady introducing a Divine Being, a different being from Herself?" No. This post speaks of a speculative topic that has no bases in Catholic doctrine.

@Ken Graham The word "I AM", is a Divine Being, a person. And my question is, if the statement, " I am the Immaculate Conception" pertain to a Divine Being a person too. Because the Dogma of IC, is only a description of how the BVM was conceived, and it's not a teaching that Mary is a Divine  Person. So, anyone can give an answer to clarify tbe answer of Our Lady in the apparition . The OP had no error in question, it is a legit question, that the downvoters here cannot explain their downvotes.

The 'Immaculate Conception' can only be referencing two; Jesus and Holy Virgin Mother Mary, but since Jesus has never been addressed as such, or no mention of it directly in the Gospel, it would have to be Holy Mary.
Why did the Apparition address herself by that name? It might be because Bernadette was or often prayed to her under that 'name' (she has many similar that Catholics may use), or she was Confirming that which the Church uses.
--- comment to
jong ricafort - I put this affirmation to your objection here as I lack the 50 (50!) score needed to place it in the correct spot. Many of the Catholic Faith aspects rejected by Protestant sects - such as Veneration of Mary, seem to receive heaps of negative votes. It is not only you that has experienced this. Also - even the smallest extrapolations away from what is written seems to receive similar, even when the question asks directly for such.

It seems that 3 comments, 2 of mine and one other I never got to read was deleated. It might be suggested that it was related to my Correction of an objection to the Question was not Catholic Doctrine, when Apparitions clear is. But perhaps it was for my statement that the Joy of finding this site has been slowly murdered by seemingly insane vindictive and-or neurotic managers.

@jong ricafort - Mary (the Immaculate Conception) while living was free from Original Sin, and it is Catholic Doctrine that she accepted God's Will with absolutely no consideration of self, ever, so in most everything she did everyday added Merit towards greater position in Heaven, although I never heard her referred to as a Divine Being when living, only after her Assumption into heaven has that Holy State applied.

Sadly, it seems that - by my count - 3 Answers of (-1) score, out of 12 Answers to 12 Questions here has somehow blocked my ability to Answer questions. So, the moderators anti-Catholics, and GramerNazis will not have me to kick-around for a while.
